# Unterschied zwischen "anwachsen" und "wachsen"

Tags: preposition, meaning

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen diesen Verben? Warum benutzt man das erste Verb in folgendem Satz?

> Hand in Hand mit dem deutschen Vermögensaufbau ist der gleiche Betrag auf den Schuldenkonten des Auslands gegenüber Deutschland angewachsen, ...

Answer (score 3):

*Anwachsen* ist hier schlicht und einfach ein Synonym zu *wachsen*, *steigen* oder *ansteigen*.

Zusätzlich kann *anwachsen* noch im biologischen Kontext vorkommen, z.B. bei einer eingebauten Pflanze oder einer Organtransplantation.

Comment: Zusätzlich kann *anwachsen* im Kontext von *festwachsen* gebraucht werden, also etwas, was sich gelöst hat, wächst wieder so, dass es wieder fest ist. ("Keine Sorge, der Finger wächst wieder an!")

Comment: Wenn eine Zielgröße mittels "auf" verbunden wird, dann ist "anwachsen" deutlich idiomatischer. "Die Schulden sind auf 5 Billionen angewachsen/gewachsen". Ich glaube "anwachsen" ist generell etwas zielorientierter. Und was noch wichtig ist, ist, dass "anwachsen" nicht im KOntext von Körpern funktioniert (Das Kind ist angewachsen... nee)